# I cannot get in my drives

Tags: mount, drive

I have Windows 8.1 running on my laptop and installed ubuntu on it 3 days before - now when i shut down windows and switch to ubuntu cannot open my drives .
it says windows still using my drives so it cannot mount it .
Check the image i attached . . .

[Attached photo](http://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=20797892537)

Comment: Link does not work. use StackExchange's preferred image hosting service https://imgur.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 1):

First you should disable fast **startup option** in Windows 8.1 , which is a feature that speed up windows booting .

As the Picture :

[image]

Uncheck Turn on fast startup and try again .

Source : [Link](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/)